# populate observable array from json when class is not defined

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, get

I am attempting to populate an observable array from a web API call but I am having a difficult time figuring it out using a jQuery get call.

It works here when I hard code in the array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead><tr>       <th>Product</th>       <th>Price</th>   </tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: products'>
            <tr>
                <td data-bind='text: name'></td>
                <td data-bind='text: price'></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        function product() {

        }
        function Model() {
            var self = this;
            this.products = ko.observableArray();
        }
        var mymodel = new Model();

            mymodel.products.push(product = { name: "Beer", price: 10.99 });
            mymodel.products.push(product = { name: "Brats", price: 7.99 });
            mymodel.products.push(product = { name: "Buns", price: 1.49 });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(mymodel);

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So next I replaced the hard coded values for the array of products with a web API call.

```
public class productController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<product> get()
        {
            List<product> products = new List<product>
        {
            new product() { name="Beer", price=10.99},
            new product() { name="Brats", price=7.99},
            new product() { name="Buns", price=1.49},
        };
            return products;
        }
```

So when I go to the URL /api/product I get.

```
[{"name":"Beer","price":10.99},{"name":"Brats","price":7.99},{"name":"Buns","price":1.49}]
```

So now I would like to populate my observable array from the web API but here is where I am getting stuck I tried.

```
function populateProducts() {

            $.getJSON("/api/products", function (myData) {
             $.each(myData, function (key, value) {

             mymodel.products.push(product =  {key: value, });

            });

             });
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

I do not want to define the class product with its attributes because when I actually do this there will be many many attributes so I just want to get them from the web API.  So I do not want to define products like this

```
 function Product(name, price) {
            this.name = ko.observable(name);
            this.price = ko.observable(price);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for [the ko-mapping library](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). For your case that would work along these lines:

```js
// Stub!
$ = { 
  getJSON: function(url, callback) {
    var fakeData = [{"name":"Beer","price":10.99},{"name":"Brats","price":7.99},{"name":"Buns","price":1.49}];
    callback(fakeData);
  }
};

// Stub!
var mymodel = { products: [] }; 

function populateProducts() {
  $.getJSON("/api/products", function (myData) {
    mymodel.products = ko.mapping.fromJS(myData);
  });
};

populateProducts();

ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: price"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```